Why priorities don't work properly in this example?
In the CSS below, the body selector has priority over the universal selector.
* {
color: rgba(255, 3, 3, 0.966);
}
body {
color: rgb(103, 231, 18);
font-family: sans-serif;
}

When I load simple HTML like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>BLOG</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>BLOG</h2>
<a href="index.html">Back to home</a>
</body>
</html>

the universal selector is applied. Why is that?
I cleared the browser cache and also tried other browsers, but it didn't work. When I specify the tag like below, it works correctly.
body h2,a {
    color: rgb(103, 231, 18);
    font-family: sans-serif;
}


So in this case universal selector is automaticlly inheritted?

The universal selector applies to all elements including the h2 and a you are using. The body selector has priority only on the elements it selects.
